# Twilio Two Factor Authentication Model for Web

Tags: php, html, twilio, twilio-php

I've got a system setup to send a 2FA code that I generate at login to a users cell phone, the basics work fine.  User logs in, they get an automatic SMS message with the code, cool...BUT, I want to enable the "AutoFill" options that I see on my computer via my iPhone when I login to other 2FA systems.

I'm assuming there's something else that I need to code into my SMS message to give the option of "AutoFill" from my phone...but I don't know what it is.  I saw a random blog that said you can just include @example.com 123456 (domain name and code) as the last line of the SMS message, but when I do that, it just includes that as text in the SMS...

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/html-attributes-two-factor-authentication-autocomplete).

> In iOS and Safari on macOS we can take advantage of this to have the browser suggest two factor authentication codes that are sent to the device over SMS. Adding the autocomplete attribute with the value "one-time-code" will trigger this behaviour.

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="token"
  id="token"
  inputmode="numeric"
  pattern="[0-9]*"
  autocomplete="one-time-code"
/>
```

For a Chrome solution,

> the Chrome team is investigating similar ideas to streamline this
> process. Currently there is an experiment with an imperative SMS
> Receiver API modelled on Android's SMS receiver API. This would allow
> developers to extract the one time password from the SMS and, because
> it's in JavaScript, instantly submit the form, saving the user more
> time.
>
> At the time of writing this API is part of an origin trial which
> allows you to test it out and feed back to the Chrome team. If this
> interests you, sign up and give the API a whirl.

Well, the blog post was made in 2020 and since then the Trial is complete. You can find more details [here](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5873577578463232).

Comment: Thanks for that, however, there must be something that you're coding into the SMS part itself...Can you give a sample of what the "message" you're sending via SMS includes?

Comment: @davidbii From what I've read, you should first change the HTML input autocomplete. Then, in your message follow the format: 

```
747723 is your ExampleCo authentication code.
    
@example.com #747723
```
You can read more [here](https://github.com/WICG/sms-one-time-codes#proposal). Since you already mentioned adding this part in your SMS, did you make sure to add autocomplete in your input box?